# three.js: shadows cast by partially transparent mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a model with a texture, and the texture is transparent in some areas (alpha is zero).

However, when the model casts a shadow, the shadow appears as if the model is solid.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19):

When casting shadows in three.js, meshes are treated as solid from the point of view of the light.

However, if your mesh has a transparent texture, or an alpha map, you can achieve proper shadows by specifying a `CustomDepthMaterial` for the mesh.

There are several ways to do that. One way is via a custom `ShaderMaterial`. There is an example of that approach in [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html).

[image: Screenshot of three.js cloth animation example]

For simpler scenes, it is sufficient to use this pattern:

```
var customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial( {

    depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,

    map: myTexture, // or, alphaMap: myAlphaMap

    alphaTest: 0.5

} );

mesh.customDepthMaterial = customDepthMaterial;
```

three.js r.85

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remember to "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. Thank you.